# osmdroid - custom view for marker

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm currently trying to develop an app, where I need a custom view to appear when tapping on a Marker. As far as I understand now, I have to create an InfoWindow that launches the View.

Do you know any tutorial that explains how to do this? Right now I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `osmDroid` document you can create a class and extend it from [InfoWindow](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocAll/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/infowindow/InfoWindow.html) and pass a CustomView (in below example I passed TextView instead) or a layout res id. Then instanciate and set it as your marker's infoWindow :

```
class CustomInfoWindow(
    private val infoTitle: String,
    mapView: MapView
) : InfoWindow(
    TextView(mapView.context).apply {
        setTextColor(Color.RED)
        text = infoTitle
    }, mapView
) {
    override fun onOpen(item: Any?) {
        // ...
    }

    override fun onClose() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and use:

```
val newMarker = Marker(mapView).apply {
    position = GeoPoint(....)
    infoWindow = CustomInfoWindow("Hello", mapView)
}
overlays.add(newMarker)
```